# How to resume where left off after sleep

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to make my Xamarin.Forms cross-platform app have the ability to resume after it sleeps.

I have been googling for a while but haven't found any solutions.

I tried reading this [Xamarin tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/app-lifecycle/) but it doesn't seem to have anything for what I am trying to accomplish.

I tried looking for something like `base.OnResume()` but there is no base variable or any methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xamarin Forms has an OnSleep and an OnResume method in the Application class

These can be used to save and restore variables when the app is backgrounded and resumed.

It is up to you to save the details you need such as page to load and state to restore. Look at the persist data section.

[Here is a blog post about doing this.](http://arteksoftware.com/backgrounding-with-xamarin-forms/)

Comment: I am using a NavigationPage so users can navigate around, that tutorial doesn't seem to explain how to use that? Like if a user navigates to their profile page I'd like next them they open from the app switcher it shows right where they left off.

Comment: Unless you close the app it should still be on the profile page.

Comment: Otherwise you could save a page name when visiting a page and check the current page on resume and navigate to saved page if different.

Answer (score 1):

You can find this methods in your app.xml file. Handle your code inside that file whatever you want to do onresume